# Split comma separated string, while ignoring sentence in quotes

Tags: python, split

I'm sure the solution isn't really complicated, but I cant seem to figure it out.

```
my_string = '2, "some text", "some more text with comma, foo bar", 42, "", 3, 4, "and some more text, hello"'
```

Want I would like to have:

```
['2', 'some text', 'some more text with comma, foo bar', '42, '', '3', '4', 'and some more text, hello']
```

so the problem is that numbers don't have quotation marks, and there can also be empty strings. Basically I want to comma separate the whole string, but not separate the sentences.

Comment: If you split on `"`, you can tell what is in a string and what is not (assuming the quotes are properly balanced) and thus what should be split on a comma and what shouldn't.

Comment: A quick workaround for proof-of-concepts, _not for production_: use `ast.literal_eval`. This should return a tuple with the string and the numbers.

Comment: @Chris this should not have been marked as duplicate

Comment: @mcsoini `pyparsing` method in the third answer works as OP expected... I agree it can be bit misleading

Comment: @mcsoini I've added another answer where the very first answer addresses the issue. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Chris Thank you Chris, I'll have a look at those answers